# Import-CSV Where-Object as an Array

Tags: powershell

I have the following code working - based on the great help here on stackoverflow - to parse a CSV file.  I would like to replace the $_.File - matches with data from a second CSV file that contains a list of files.

```
Import-csv "D:\NTFSInfo_C_.csv" -header("File","ParentName","Extension","Attributes","SizeInBytes","CreationDate","LastModificationDate","LastAccessDate","LastAttrChangeDate","Status","USN","FRN","ParentFRN","FileNameCreationDate","FileNameLastModificationDate","FileNameLastAccessDate","FileNameLastAttrModificationDate")|
  Where-Object{($_.File -match "null.sys") -or ($_.File -match "explorer.exe")} |
  Select-Object File, CreationDate, FileNameCreationDate, ParentName |
  Export-CSV -Path c:\NTFS_KNOW_IOC.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Question.  How do I read a list of file names from a TXT or CSV into an array and then use that array in the Where-Object as shown above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
$files = Get-Content files.txt
...

Where-Object{($files -match "null.sys") -or ($files -match "explorer.exe")} ...
```

Comment: Thanks Shay.  When I test the code... The files from my files.txt file loads.  Thanks.  It seems that the where-object doesnt loop through the files list.  Do I need do add a loop to get this going?

Comment: No, the code doesn't loop through the file list, it just checks if there's a match.

Comment: cool.  If I wanted to check what was in files.txt against the data in NTFSInfo_C_.csv I would just add a loop?  Or is there some sneaky cool way to do it in PS?  thanks for you time.